# WooCommerce hooks - How to pass variables such as $product in the hooked function?

Tags: php, variables, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to understand how to pass variables such as ***$product*** in the hooked function as shown in the following code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text', 9999, 2 ); 
function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text($text, $product) {
  if ( is_product() ) {
    if ( 999 === $product->get_id() ) {
      $text = __( 'Donate', 'woocommerce' );
    }

 }
 return $text; 
}
```

I understand how that function works.
I'm not sure to understand how to know which variable is available for a given hook and how to find it out. For example, how do I know that in this hook ***$text*** and ***$product*** are available to use?
Could anyone try to clarify this question?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use global $`product` object

```
// Change add to cart text on archives depending on product type
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
    function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {
        global $product;
        
        $product_type = $product->product_type;
        
        switch ( $product_type ) {

            case 'simple':
                return __( 'ADD!', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
            case 'variable':
                return __( 'Select the variations, yo!', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
            default:
                return __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but in [`woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1864), there are 2 arguments missing from your function: `$button_text` and `$product`… so `global $product;` is not needed!

Comment: Ok, so if I understand well, I should look at the origin of the hook. If I find the arguments are passed with the hook, I can just use them, if not then I need to use global $variable. Right? Thanks!